# News Ticker - auto change div with next and previous buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to JQuery so please be gentle.  I have a news ticker built up in html and css with JQuery activating the next and previous buttons.  I am looking get the div's to auto play on load but still allow the user to use the navigation buttons.  I seem to be able to get either the navigation or the auto play to work but not together.  Any chance someone can help me out.  I know I am missing something big but I can't seem to figure it out.
My code can be seen here -

http://jsfiddle.net/s8qotsj2/8/

HTML

```
<div id="myNewsticker">

<div id="newsNav">
    <a href="#" id="prev"><img src="images/back.png"></a><a href="#" id="next"><img src="images/next.png"></a>
</div>

<div class="tickerlable">News:</div>
    <div class="newsContent">
        <div class="newsTicker active">School closed 12/12/15 - Snow Day - All Classes Closed</div>

        <div class="newsTicker">Checkout our New Website.</div>

        <div class="newsTicker">New Students Handbook Now Available.</div>

        <div class="newsTicker">Resouces Links Have Been Added to the Navigation Bar</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#myNewsticker{
float: right;
margin-top: 20px;
margin-right: 8px;
width: 460px;
border-radius: 25px;
padding: 0 20px;
background: #851818;
color: white;
font-size: 14px;
font-family: calibri;
}

.tickerLable {
margin: 5px;
padding: 5px;
max-width: 38px;
}

#myNewsticker .newsTicker {
display: none;   
}

#myNewsticker .newsTicker.active{
display: block; 
}

.newsTicker {
margin-top: -32px;
padding: 5px;
max-width: 400px;
float: left;
margin-left: 60px;
}

#newsNav {
padding-top: 3px;
width: 51px;
float: right;
margin-right: 15px;
margin-top: 3px;
}

#prev img, #next img{
width: 25px; /***changes size of images height and width****/
}
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var news = $(".newsTicker");
var newsIndex = -1;

function showNextNews() {
++newsIndex;
news.eq(newsIndex % news.length)
.fadeIn(2000)
.delay(2000)
.fadeOut(2000, showNextNews);
}

showNextNews();

}) ();

$(function () {
$("#next").click(function () {
var activeDiv = $("div.active");
activeDiv.removeClass("active");
if (activeDiv.next().length === 0) {
$("div.newsTicker").eq(0).addClass("active").css("opacity", 0).animate({
opacity: 1
}, 800);
} else {
activeDiv.next().addClass("active").css("opacity", 0).animate({
opacity: 1
}, 800);
}
});

$("#prev").click(function () {
var activeDiv = $("div.active");
activeDiv.removeClass("active");
if (activeDiv.prev().length === 0) {
$("div.newsTicker").eq(-1).addClass("active").css("opacity", 0).animate({
opacity: 1
}, 800);
} else {
activeDiv.prev().addClass("active").css("opacity", 0).animate({
opacity: 1
}, 800);
}
});
});
```

Comment: You already are navigating feeds on button click. Now you can create a `setInterval` that will loop for some time and on elapsed, click on necessary button. Also to stop, you can `clearInterval` on hover. This should work.

Comment: That worked perfectly Thanks so much.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.  I even added the clearIntraval to pause on hover.  Any idea on how to update the content via xml file for on the fly updates.

Answer (score 0):

```
function next_item() {
   do some stuff here;  
}
$(document).ready(function() { 
   //maybe wait 5 secs? 
   next_item();
}
$(".next_buttons").on('click', function() {
    next_item();
    //maybe disable the button, till next element is ready
}
```

Now add what you need to the first function